# "Not a valid framework" (MM0140) error when trying to build Xamarin native bindings library for framework targeting net6-macos

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have working native bindings library targeting old xamarin.mac (xamarin.full net framework 4.8) built with mono.
It is binding `ScritptingBridge.framework`, not a static library. It is builds and works as expected.

Note: full project for experiments may be found here: https://github.com/snechaev/net6nativeBindingsError

Now I'm trying to migrate to newest net6-macos. To do so I do the following

- converted main app project to the sdk style and target net6-macos. If I will temporary remove native bindings dependencies, this will build fine.
- converted native bindings project to the sdk style and perform the following fixes suggested by the comiler errors

  - changed version to avoid wildcards
  - replaced `[assembly: LinkerSafe]` with `AssemblyMetadata("IsTrimmable", "True")]`
  - added explicit `NativeReferecnce` to the framework I'm trying to bind.

Final csproj content for native bindings project:

```
    <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6-macos</TargetFramework>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
        <RootNamespace>NativeBindingsLib</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>NativeBindingsLib</AssemblyName>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <AllowUnsafeBlocks>false</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
        <IsBindingProject>true</IsBindingProject>
        <NoBindingEmbedding>true</NoBindingEmbedding>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <ObjcBindingApiDefinition Include="ApiDefinition.cs" />
        <ObjcBindingCoreSource Include="StructsAndEnums.cs" />
        <NativeReference Include="/System/Library/Frameworks/ScriptingBridge.framework" Kind="Framework" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

When I trying to build the only bindings library with `dotnet build` it builds without errors.

But when I try to build the application project (`app.csproj` in the sample repository), which is referencing (via the the `ProjectReference`) the binding library, I got the following errors:

```
ILLINK: Error MM0140: File '/Users/user/work/MonoBindingTest/net6/app/obj/Debug/net6.0-macos/osx-x64/linker-cache/NativeBindingsLib.resources/ScriptingBridge.framework/ScriptingBridge' is not a valid framework. (MM0140) (app)
       
ILLINK: Error MM2342: The linker step 'Extract Binding Libraries' failed during processing: File '/Users/user/work/MonoBindingTest/net6/app/obj/Debug/net6.0-macos/osx-x64/linker-cache/NativeBindingsLib.resources/ScriptingBridge.framework/ScriptingBridge' is not a valid framework. (MM2342) (app)
```

I double checked the framework path and it is ok. I also tried to add `ScriptingBridge.framework` into the XCode project and verified that the path is the same.

I also will be happy to get any samples of working `net6-macos` targeted native bindings projects for *frameworks* (not a static libraries) for further experiments on my own.

Full project mey be found here (both mono-targeted and net6-targeted): https://github.com/snechaev/net6nativeBindingsError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I posted the issue in the xamarin repo on github https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15485.

And ducting the discussion and experiments we concluded the following:

- MM0140 is because the `ScriptingBridge` is the *system* framework and this is the special case.
- you should not use `NativeReference` for the *system* frameworks as it will try to copy the framework into your bundle and this is not what you want for the system framework
- initially I was missleaded by the following error

  ```
  MSBuild : error MM7068: Can't create a binding resource package unless there are native references in the binding project.
  ```

  so I decided to add `NativeReference` pointing `ScriptingBridge`.

So, the final solution is that the "at least one `NativeReference`" compiler check is excessive and it will be removed it net7 (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/15489).

The temporary workaround for net6 is to add the fake `NativeReference` to the empty static library to make compiler happy.

```
<NativeReference Include="/Users/sergey/work/MonoBindingTest/net6/test.dylib" Kind="Static"/>
```

I believe that it is possible to specify `NativeReference` to point to the source code (C++) instead of binary file and provide an additional command to build such a C++ code into the binary during the build process of native bindings library.

Additional note: the MM0140 error was called MT0140 in the previous versions of xamarin. So, this note may help other to find this post.